# Mysql Statement in html

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, html

Im using the following code to create a table product via mysql statement, the insert part for the table product is being done correctly. I have also created another table (product_add). I want to add only one specific row from table product to the table product_add as soon as I click on the button ADD which Im unable to do. The button Add will appear on a row when im inserting data for the table product.

```
 <body> 
 <div data-role=page id=home>
<div data-role=header>
 <h1>Home</h1>
 </div>

 <div data-role=content>
  <a href=# data-role=button id=create> Create product table </a>
<a href=# data-role=button id=remove> Delete product table </a>
<a href=# data-role=button id=create_add> Create product_add table </a>
<a href=# data-role=button id=remove_add> Delete product_add table </a>

  <span> Name </span>
<input type=text id=name>
<span> Description </span>
<input type=text id=description>
<span> Category </span>
<input type=text id=category>
<span> Price </span>
<input type=text id=price>  

<a href=# data-role=button id=insert> Insert the product </a>   
<a href=# data-role=button id=list> List product </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role=page id=win2 data-add-back-btn=true>

<div data-role=header>
<h1>List of product</h1>
 </div>
 <a href=# data-role=button id=cart>View Cart</a>
<div data-role=content>
</div>
</div>  
 <div data-role=page id=win3 data-add-back-btn=true>
  <div data-role=header>
  <h1>List of product in cart</h1>
 </div>
<div data-role=content>
</div>
</div>

  </body>
  </html>

 <script>

  var db = openDatabase ("pascal", "1.0", "pascal", 1024);

   $("#create").bind ("click", function (event)
   {
   db.transaction (function (transaction) 
     {
   var sql = "CREATE TABLE product" +
    " (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " + 
    "description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " + 
    "category VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "+
    "price INTEGER(10)NOT NULL)"
     transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, function ()
    { 
     alert ("Table created");
     }, error);
  });
});

$("#create_add").bind ("click", function (event)
{
  db.transaction (function (transaction) 
 {
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE product_add" +
    " (pid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "prod_id INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
    "name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " + 
    "price INTEGER(10)NOT NULL)"
   transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, function ()
  { 
    alert ("Table created");
     }, error);
   });
 });

  $("#remove").bind ("click", function (event)
   {
   if (!confirm ("Delete table?", "")) return;;
    db.transaction (function (transaction) 
  {
    var sql = "DROP TABLE product";
     transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, ok, error);
    });
  });


   $("#remove_add").bind ("click", function (event)
   {
   if (!confirm ("Delete table?", "")) return;;
   db.transaction (function (transaction) 
   {
     var sql = "DROP TABLE product_add";
     transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, ok, error);
   });
 });


  $("#insert").bind ("click", function (event)
  {
    var name = $("#name").val ();
    var description = $("#desc").val ();
  var category = $("#category").val ();
  var price = $("#price").val ();

    db.transaction (function (transaction) 
   {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO product(name, descrition, category, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    transaction.executeSql (sql, [name, description, category, price], function ()
    { 
     alert ("Product added");
      }, error);
     });
    });

     function add(){
    alert("Button ADD has been triggered...");
    db.transaction (function (transaction) 
   {
       var sql = "INSERT INTO product_add (prod_id, name, price) SELECT id, name, price     

     FROM product ";
      transaction.executeSql (sql, [id, name, price], function ()
     { 
      alert ("Product inserted to cart");
     }, error);
   });
 }//end function add

 $("#list").bind ("click", function (event)
 {
  db.transaction (function (transaction) 
 {
   var sql = "SELECT *  FROM product";
   transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, 
  function (transaction, result)
  {
      var html = "<ul>";
      if (result.rows.length)
     {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
       {
      var row = result.rows.item (i);
      var name = row.name;
      var description = row.description;
      var category = row.category;
      var price = row.price;
        html +=  "<li>"+ name + "&nbsp;" + description + "&nbsp;" + category + "&nbsp;" +  

     price + "<input type='submit' id='add' value='ADD' onclick='add();'></a>" + "

     </li>";
       }
     }
      else
     {
         html += "<li> No Product found </li>";
        }

       html += "</ul>";

        $("#win2").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()
          {
             var $content = $("#win2 div:jqmData(role=content)");
          $content.html (html);
         var $ul = $content.find ("ul");
          $ul.listview ();
     });

    $.mobile.changePage ($("#win2"));

       }, error);
   });
  });

   $("#cart").bind ("click", function (event)
   {
  db.transaction (function (transaction) 
   {
   var sql = "SELECT prod_id, name, price  FROM product_add";
   transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, 
   function (transaction, result)
    {
     var html = "<ul>";
     if (result.rows.length)
            {
       for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
         {
       var row = result.rows.item (i);
       var name = row.name;
       var description = row.description;
     // var category = row.category;
      var price = row.price;
       html +=  "<li>"+ name + "&nbsp;" + description + "&nbsp;" + price + "<input 

      type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>" + "</li>";
        }
      }
     else
       {
    html += "<li> No Product found </li>";
      }

          html += "</ul>";

            $("#win3").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()
        {
           var $content = $("#win3 div:jqmData(role=content)");
             $content.html (html);
        var $ul = $content.find ("ul");
         $ul.listview ();
        });

       $.mobile.changePage ($("#win3"));

      }, error);
    });
   });

  function ok ()
 {
 }

   function error (transaction, err) 
 {
   alert ("DB error : " + err.message);
   return false;
 }

  </script>
```

Comment: desc is a reserved word

Comment: your question is too long post the problematic code and its related peices